# Ejecución automática de scripts al encender Linux

Tags: shell

Estoy teniendo problemas para que un script python y mjpg-streamer se ejecuten y queden abiertos en segundo plano. Lo que he hecho es en `/ect/rc.local` añadir dos lineas:

```
python /home/pi/Desktop/scriptarranque.py

cd mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/ && ./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so"
```

Al iniciar solo se activa el primero de los dos. El otro estoy seguro que funciona ya que si lo pongo en el terminal me funciona sin problemas pero no se porque no se inicia con el sistema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías agregar el caracter & al final de la primera linea para que el script de python se ejecute en segundo plano y permita continuar con la ejecución de la siguiente linea en el script.

```
python /home/pi/Desktop/scriptarranque.py &
cd mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/ && ./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so"
```

Mas información aquí https://askubuntu.com/a/539293